Flutter package name conflict after switching laptops and cloning repository
Problem Overview:
I was working on a Flutter project on my old laptop, and everything was fine. After storing my project code on GitHub, I cloned the repository on a new laptop to continue development. However, after setting up the environment and running the project, I'm encountering a package name conflict that I can't resolve.
I've tried several troubleshooting steps, but the issue persists. I need help resolving this issue.
Steps I've Taken:

Cloned the repository on a new laptop and installed all necessary dependencies.
Ran flutter clean to remove any cached files.
Ran flutter pub get and flutter pub upgrade to update dependencies.
Deleted the pubspec.lock file and regenerated it with flutter pub get.
Checked the Flutter version with flutter --version and ensured that both the old and new laptops are on the same version.
Verified the Android project’s applicationId and iOS project’s bundle identifier.
Reinstalled the Flutter dependencies with flutter pub cache repair.
Cleared any local device caches and uninstalled the app from the emulator/device.
Checked for any unresolved Git merge conflicts that could have caused the issue.

Error Message:
The exact error message I’m seeing is:
田 Console ↑ ↓ Launching 1ib\main_development.dart on SM M146B in debug mode.... Running Gradle task 'assemble DevelopmentDebug' ✓ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-development-debug.apk Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-development-debug.apk... Error: ADB exited with exit code 1 Performing Streamed Install adb: failed to install C:\Users\***\Desktop\***Project\Fronted\****\******-flutter\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-development-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Existing package com.****.***.dev signatures do not match newer version; ignoring!] Error launching application on SM M1468.

Environment:
Flutter 3.22.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision a14f74ff3a (7 months ago) • 2024-05-22 11:08:21 -0500
Engine • revision 55eae6864b
Tools • Dart 3.4.1 • DevTools 2.34.3
What I Have Tried So Far:

Flutter clean and pub get: I’ve already run flutter clean and flutter pub get multiple times.
Check for version mismatch: Verified that both laptops have the same version of Flutter/Dart.
Checked Android/iOS configurations: Ensured that package names in build.gradle and Info.plist are correctly set.
Cleared cache: Ran flutter pub cache repair to fix any corrupted cache.

Question:
Has anyone experienced similar package name conflicts when moving a Flutter project from one laptop to another? What steps can I take to resolve the issue and ensure the project runs correctly on the new machine?
The project should build and run successfully on my new laptop without any package name conflicts.

Try to remove already installed app then try to run again.

seems like you are using default keystore for run app. just uninstall old app from device and run this app again

INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE error stops because when the APK is signed and an attempt is made to install there is no consistency with the version signing that already exists:

The application version key was changed, such as changing from a development build to a production build.
It involves installing a package name variant of the package but with the same key on the device.

Solution:

Uninstall the existing app before installing the new version.

Solutions to Resolve

adb uninstall com.*..dev

Run app again

flutter run


Enable --no-shared-runtime in Flutter.

If you are using different branches (production and development), to avoid signing conflict errors, make sure that the versions are completely independent.
android {
    flavorDimensions "default"
    productFlavors {
        development {
            applicationId "com.example.myapp.dev"
        }
        production {
            applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        }
    }
}


Using the same signing key:
If the problem persists try changing the signing key in the application, try to check is the keys is the same in the file android/app/build.gradle.

`
signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias 'your-key-alias'
        keyPassword 'your-key-password'
        storeFile file('your-key.jks')
        storePassword 'your-store-password'
    }
}

`
